# Python Error: read the contents in a file into variable

Tags: python

I was doing this in shell successfully

```
readonly FILE="/home/xxxx/file.txt"
text=$(cat ${FILE})
```

Trying the same in python

```
text = open('file.txt').read()
print text
```

I am trying this and got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py", line 170, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py", line 162, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py", line 106, in compile
    with open(file, 'U') as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename: ''
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you put does not seem to match the traceback you posted. In the trackeback you appear to be using a context manager for it. Can you please clarify this.

Comment: `text = open('file.txt', 'r').read()`

Answer (score 1):

This line in your traceback :`IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename: ''` tells me that you are feeding your context manager an empty string for the file name. Make sure that the variable `file` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can define read mode in the `open()` method.

Please try `text = open('file.txt','r')`

Comment: That's true, but I don't think that this is the OP's problem. You can `.read()` a file in 'U' mode as well.